# showing jquery UI Dialog on focus won't focus the element

Tags: jquery-ui, focus, jquery-dialog

I want to display an jquery UI dialog when a user focues a certain  input box. It works the problem is, that the input box won't get the focus after closing the dialog, meaning user clicks into input box, dialog is opened. User closes dialog -> input box does not have focus.

The only way to actually focus the input box is ti click into it a second time while the dialog is already displayed. This is pretty annoying. i would like the inputbox to have focus after closing the dialog.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#identifiersDialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false});
});        
$('#identifiers').focus(function(event) {
     $( "#identifiersDialog" ).dialog('open');           
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
$(function(){
    InitiliseInput();    
});
function InitiliseInput(){
    $('#identifiers').bind('focus', function() {
        $('#identifiersDialog').dialog({ close: function() { 
            $('#identifiers').unbind('focus').focus().blur(function(){ InitiliseInput()});              
        }});
    }); 
}
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/RCBQs/1/

The `blur` function then resets the dialog once the focus has moved away from the input, so that refocusing opens the dialog again.

Comment: works. But you need to add $('#identifiersDialog').hide(); else the div containing the text for the dialog is displayed on the page.

Comment: do you have the stylesheet for the dialog? when a jQueryUI dialog closes, it always hides unless you dont have the stylesheet OR make sure the #identifiersDialog style is set to `display: none;` by default

Answer (score -1):

This should help.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#identifiersDialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, close: function() { $('#identifiers').focus()  }});
});        
$('#identifiers').focus(function(event) {
     $( "#identifiersDialog" ).dialog('open');           
});
```

Comment: This would result in your dialog opening straight back up again when closing.